# Modifying a file from within an executable - permission denied in XP (but not Vista)

Tags: c++, windows-vista, windows-xp, file-permissions

I have an application where I need to open an xml file, modify it, and close it again. When I test the code on a laptop running Windows Vista, it works perfectly, but under Windows XP I can't even open the file for read/write access:

```
errno_t _wfopen_s(&inStream, m_fileName, L"r+, ccs = UTF-8");
```

...without getting an error code 13, "Permission denied" (although the file will open without any problems if I select "r" rather than "r+' to specify read-only access). Yet the permissions on the file are all set appropriately, as far as I can see, and the file can be opened and modified from the GUI without difficulty.

What could possibly be causing this? Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Where is the file located on both OSes ? Did you try to execute your program with administrative credentials ?

Comment: On Vista it is located in "My Documents"; on XP I have tried both "My Documents" and "C:\Program Files", but the behaviour was the same in each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, with r+ you will ask for write access to the file.  A privilege that is harder to come by, do triple-check that the user account indeed has the write privilege in the folder.

But sounds like you already checked that.  The next consideration is sharing.  The fopen() function is quite inappropriate on modern multitasking operating systems, it allows any process to access the opened file and both read and write to it.  That rarely comes to a good end, especially write sharing can only produce garbage if the processes don't negotiate access to the file.

That's why there's an fopen_s() in the Microsoft CRT, it makes sure that write sharing is denied.  It is very rare that you'd want to allow it.  When you pass "r" then read sharing is allowed.  When you pass "r+" then *no* sharing is allowed.  That can fail if some other process already has the file opened for reading.

You need to find that other process.  The SysInternals' Handle utility can help you find it.  **Also consider that it might be your own program.**

In general, take charge of controlling the sharing yourself, use the _wfsopen() function instead.  Note that there's no secure version for it because none is needed.

Comment: Much earlier in the program the file is opened by an IXMLReader in order for its contents to be read in during initialisation. I wonder if it's possible that XP isn't closing it properly afterwards, whereas Vista is. I'll investigate this...

Comment: Yes, that was it. When I had a closer look at my code for doing the initial reading of the file using IXMLReader, I found that it wasn't being explicitly closed. When I changed to code to ensure that it really was closed, my application worked.

Obviously there is some difference in behaviour between XP and Vista here, in how they implement iXMLReader. The XP behaviour is probably more correct; Vista is more accommodating, and this gave me a false sense of security!

Anyway, thanks for the pointer which set me in the right direction.

Stephen.

Comment: @Eos: no sure why this thread isn't marked answered yet.  Do you need something else?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question in this forum and it took me a while to figure out how to do it.